# Can't use vim as root

Tags: raspbian, root

Hey Pi user out there!

I got a  Raspberry pi model B with Raspbian Wheezy.
I want to play around at  `init` and my Kernel...

But  to do this I need to run `vim` as root.
When I start vim this happens:

```
# vim hosts.allow
-bash: vim: command not found
```

What's up here?

I installed vim, and with the user `pi` it's running perfect:

Comment: I use sudo vi /etc/hosts.allow without any problem

Comment: I reinstalled vim, now everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have a problem with your path. Type `which vim` as the user it works fore, and use the full path as root, or make sure the directory with the program is in root's PATH variable.

Comment: I edited my PATH before asking this question. That's not the problem.

Comment: Did you edit `PATH` for root, or for your user? How did you edit it? Did you make the change persistent?

Comment: I edited for root, and it didn't work directly after editing PATH, but how to change path persistent?

Comment: Ok. What is the output of `which vim` as user? What is the output of `echo $PATH` as root?

Comment: output of wich vim:`/usr/bin/vim` $PATH:`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: Good. That seems about right. What is the output of `which vim` as root? What happens if you run `/usr/bin/vim` as root?

Comment: output of `# wich vim`: `-su: wich: command not found`

Comment: output of `# . /usr/bin/vim`:`-su: .: /usr/bin/vim: cannot execute binary file`, Why is there -su? I'm logged in as root!

Comment: Aren't you? The hash (`#`) usually signifies root shell. Anyway, the `.` you put here idicates that the shell should source the file you give it as if it was a script. Remove the initial `.` and just type `/usr/bin/vim` at the shell, as root. What happens? What is the result of a `whoami`?

Comment: I reinstalled vim, now everything works fine